# What is the meaning of the Threshold value field when creating an Alerting policy in Cloud Monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have create a default alerting policy that notifies the user when the number of requests served by an external HTTP(S) load balancer is more than a certain threshold value.

In the Google cloud console, from the main navigation menu, I selected **Monitoring** > **Alerting**.

On the Alerting page, I clicked on **Create policy**.

In the **Select a metric** menu, the resource type for an external HTTP(S) load balancer that I have selected is `https_lb_rule` and the metric to monitor the number of requests served by the load balancer that I have selected is `https/request_count`.

For a trigger condition of type `Threshold`, I have entered the following information:
Alert trigger:  Any time series violates
Threshold position: Above threshold
Threshold value: 1

Now I don't quite understand what does it mean to set the threshold value as `1`. I was under the erroneous assumption that entering a value of `1` means that the alert is triggered if more than one request is served by the load balancer.

The email notification that I get for the incident says the following:

`Request count for l7-http-gfev3 Google Cloud HTTP/S Load Balancing Rule labels {project_id=l7-http-gfev3, region=global, url_map_name=web-map-http, forwarding_rule_name=web-frontend-service, target_proxy_name=web-map-http-target-proxy, matched_url_path_rule=UNMATCHED, backend_target_name=web-backend-service} with metric labels {cache_result=MISS, client_country=United Kingdom, protocol=HTTP/1.1, proxy_continent=Europe, response_code=404, response_code_class=400} is above the threshold of 1.000 with a value of 5.000.`
The trailing segment of the message says: `is above the threshold of 1.000 with a value of 5.000`.

In another notification, the trailing segment of the message says:  `is above the threshold of 1.000 with a value of 35.000.`

So, how should I interpret this message and what is the significance/meaning of threshold value of `1` or any other value in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you selected :

```
Alert trigger: Any time series violates 
Threshold position: Above threshold
Threshold value:1
```

Here, Threshold value indicates the cut off value. If you select `above the threshold` value then if there is any request more than 1 then the alert will generate. If you select `below the threshold` value then if there is a request less than 1 then the alert will generate.
Any time if the series violates the threshold then the alert gets triggered.

As per your email, The trailing segment of the message says: is above the threshold of 1.000 with value of 5.000  **which means request count is more than 1 and the request count at the time of email generation is 5.**

In another notification, the trailing segment of the message says:  is above the threshold of 1.000 with a value of 35.000 likewise above, **request count is more than 1 and the count at the time of email generation the request count is 35.**

Refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#google-cloud-console) to know the Behavior of metric-based alerting policies

Edit 1 :

[image]

Comment: So, in this case, is it right to say that time-series data for `https/request_count` metric is synonymous with the request count?

Comment: @Nosail : Yes it is a request count, you can see the attached screenshot under edit 1 in the answer section. if your external request is more than 1 (given threshold) then the alert will trigger to your mail box.