# What is the meaning of `threshold` for an SLO based alert

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I am trying to set up Google SLO based alert policy but I am confused by the thresholdValue.

I am looking at these docs:
https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/slo-monitoring/api/create-policy-api

And they simply say:

> A condition for an SLO does set the comparison, thresholdValue,
> duration, and trigger fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from [Hemanth Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74431517/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-threshold-value-field-when-creating-an-alerting-polic),

As you selected :

Alert trigger: Any time series violates
Threshold position: Above threshold
Threshold value:1
Here, Threshold value indicates the cut off value. If you select above the threshold value then if there is any request more than 1 then the alert will generate. If you select below the threshold value then if there is a request less than 1 then the alert will generate. Any time if the series violates the threshold then the alert gets triggered.

As per your email, The trailing segment of the message says: is above the threshold of 1.000 with value of 5.000 which means request count is more than 1 and the request count at the time of email generation is 5.

In another notification, the trailing segment of the message says: is above the threshold of 1.000 with a value of 35.000 likewise above, request count is more than 1 and the count at the time of email generation the request count is 35.

Refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#google-cloud-console) to know the Behavior of metric-based alerting policies

Edit 1 :

[image]

Comment: Thank you - I understand that part, but I am trying to figure out what it means in the context of an SLO based alert.

The `select_slo_burn_rate` should compute using the look back period what the threshold should be.

So if I set a rolling window of 30 days, with a look back of 24hr, then if 5/100 failed then most likely my 0.95 SLO would be broken, even if over 30 days i can manage150 failures. Is the threshold a type of "statistical significant" - if it is less than x requests, ignore the volume of failures?